# can't see my js file in Chrome console when added asyncly within easyui tab

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-easyui, javascript-debugger

I'm using MVC + easyui.
The "missing" js file is within a "view" which is added asyncly via easyui tabs.
I found that the js file is actually working, but the problem is I cannot find it in chrome console anymore, which means I cannot debug my js.
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Js file under body tag in the view file.